# Can constructors help me? (i.e. What good are constructors in JavaScript?)

Tags: javascript

I've written some nice wrappers using the Google charts + jQuery APIs that do nice updates when you mouseover. I'm currently refactoring my code. I have functions that return Objects with attributes, which themselves have other attributes, and so on. There are a lot of functions that return arrays full of objects with attributes, some of which are arrays, etc.

Here is an example of my code that loads collections of ROC and likelihood tables from an ajax XML tree:

```
function XMLAttributeTable(subtree, point_name, arr_of_attributes) {
    // note: assumes numeric attribute values
    var attributes_for_each_point = [];
    $(subtree).find(point_name).each(function() {
    row = $(this);
    var point = {};
    arr_of_attributes.forEach( function(attr_name) { 
        point[attr_name] = parseFloatPlus(row.attr(attr_name));
    });
    attributes_for_each_point.push(point);
    });

    return attributes_for_each_point;
}

function XMLAttributeTableCollection(subtree, instance_name, point_name, arr_of_attributes) {
    // note: assumes the series are in order
    var tables_for_each_instance = [];
    $(subtree).find(instance_name).each( function() {
    tables_for_each_instance.push( XMLAttributeTable( this, "point", arr_of_attributes ) );
    });
    return tables_for_each_instance;
}

function getROCSeriesForEachRanking(roc_subtree) {
    return XMLAttributeTableCollection(roc_subtree, 'roc_series', 'point', ['index', 'target_groups', 'q_value']);
}

function getLikelihoodSeriesForEachRanking(likelihood_subtree) {
    return XMLAttributeTableCollection(likelihood_subtree, 'likelihood_series', 'point', ['index', 'likelihood']);
}
```

There are a lot of these functions, and I'm not really a fan of this (it feels very difficult to separate concerns). I may be guilty of trying to program JavaScript using semantics from other languages (i.e. C++), and if that's the case, thanks for your advice. But I can't shake the feeling that there is code smell.

So my question is, what good are constructors in JavaScript? If there are no practical options for strong typing or forcing encapsulation, then why use constructors at all? I can't seem to figure out how I would use member functions anyway to make my life better in this scenario, and so "inheritance" doesn't seem very useful.

Thanks a lot for any advice you can offer.

Comment: What are you calling _constructors_?  You have functions that just create objects and return them.  The term _constructor_ in JavaScript is usually used for functions that are designed to be called with the **new** operator; they implicitly create and return a new object, initializing its properties using the **this** expression.  Are you referring to those kinds of things, or the functions being used the way you are using them?

Comment: @RayToal Exactly my question-- is there any advantage to using constructors here instead? Can it help me with separation of concerns or to organize my code better?

Comment: @Oliver constructors allow for prototyping and inheritance, but it seems to me that you're more looking for a way to clean up your namespace, so I'll say this: _Objects_ can have methods, _functions_ can be properties of _objects_. Create an object to serve as the domain for all your related functions.

Comment: @Oliver your JavaScript code _really_ looks like C++ or Java code, use object literals instead of 8-parameter functions, it will make your code more readable. I understand your frustration, maybe read "Learning JavaScript design patterns" by Addy Osmani?

Answer (score 0):

Although JavaScript is dynamically and weakly typed, and it would appear that the use of the operator `new` is a device thrown in by Brendan Eich to make the language look more like C and Java when he really wanted a Scheme-like language to begin with (see [this post by Brendan Eich](https://brendaneich.com/2008/04/popularity/) for more on this apochryphal story), you *may* get a few advantages from constructors:

1. A lot of people have been using constructors since the early days of JavaScript and will readily understand your code.
2. The very use of the **new** operator in the expression that creates your object looks like it is creating a new object.  If your function is called `XmlAttributeTable` and you call it as a function without using `new`, then it isn't too clear you are creating anything.  That said, if you called your method `newTable` or `createTable` or `makeTable` then that would be okay too.
3. Constructors come with a little bit of magic that you would need extra lines of code to make happen if you used `Object.create`.  This includes simplifying construction and having prototypes have constructor property ready-to-go.

Consider:

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
}
```

versus

```
function makePoint(x, y) {
    var point = Object.create(theProtoPointIDeclaredEarlier);
    point.x = x;
    point.y = y;
    return this;
}
```

I've read several times that `Object.create` should be preferred to using `new` but really I don't see operator `new` as being so evil.  I know a lot of people might disagree here and that's fine.  Eich claimed to have made some "mistakes" in the 10-day design of JavaScript (see his keynote talk at JSConf 2010) but I've never heard him regret constructors.

So IMHO a constructor-style of coding *may* help you with readability, especially if you are creating a large number of objects that all appear to belong to the same type.  However, such a style may not suit you.

1. If you have a number of one-off objects which do not look like they all belong to the same "type" then please just avoid constructors and deal with objects as containers of named properties.  This is totally fine.
2. Please do remember that JavaScript is not a class-based OOP language so use prototypes if you need to derive properties.  Inheritance is not something you would care about deeply in a language like JavaScript (and Crockford makes this point well in a couple different places).  Just because inheritance doesn't help you, though, doesn't need constructors are wrong.  Constructors can be used without doing any kind of inheritance.

So whether you want to go with constructors or not IMHO comes down to whether you have a lot of objects that look the same versus whether you have one-off objects.  But you can easily do without them.  Especially in the former case, prototype objects can nicely hold common behavior.  But you can put common behavior in a prototype with `Object.create` as well.

While you are asking about "code smells" I would probably do without the getter methods.  Modern JavaScript allows you to make properties with a `get` attribute, which is clean when you want to read properties and execute code in doing so.  Better IMHO than naming a method stating with `get`.  Furthermore if your getter isn't just accessing a property, you can find a better name.

Comment: Both versions of `Point` are stupid, If you have `x` and `y` and want to make a point the sensible thing to do is `{x:x,y:y}` _that_ is embracing the language :)

Comment: I don't disagree in the case of points; it was just an example to show the extra code involved in using `Object.create`.  When many objects are created with shared behavior in the form of "methods" you will want a prototype to hold the shared behavior, because thousands of objects with their own copies of identical functions would be, in your words, stupid. :)